# PHP stuck while writing image stream data with ImageMagick

Tags: php, image, cron, imagemagick

i have a few days problem when i creating a image.

I have got an API where i get all images as array (RETS). But images are storing as binary data (not a files url, somewhere in the server). But also there is a corrupted image data where i can't check it is valid or not. I have to pull everything (those all data) create image of each array element in the server. It's like a task of cron-job. But the problem, when i get the corrupted image, my task (php process) getting stuck and can't kill it.

Rets library: https://github.com/troydavisson/PHRETS

here is example how i try with [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/):

```
<?php

$path = '/var/www/assets/photo/test.jpg';
$image = new Imagick();

/** @var PHRETS\Models\Object $photo */

// from the $photo->getContent() i get the image binary data
if($image->readImageBlob($photo->getContent()) && $image->valid()) {
    // all photos looks like ok, but... when i try to run this command:
    $image->writeImage($path); // here php process is stuck if image is corrupted
}
```

what i mean when i'am saying image are corrupted, here is example:

[image: corrupted image (grey foreground at the bottom)]

in the bottom there is grey foreground, looks like it's not finished to write or i get the bad image.

**What i try to do:**

1. somewhere in the StackOverflow i found the algorithm to check grey color from the bottom:

   ```
   function isGoodImage($fileData) {
       list($w, $h) = getimagesizefromstring($fileData);

       if ($w < MIN_WIDTH || $h < MIN_HEIGHT) return 0;

       $im = imagecreatefromstring($fileData);
       $grey = 0;

       for ($i = 0; $i < 5; ++$i) {
           for ($j = 0; $j < 5; ++$j) {
               $x = $w - 5 + $i;
               $y = $h - 5 + $j;
               list($r, $g, $b) = array_values(imagecolorsforindex($im, imagecolorat($im, $x, $y)));
               if ($r == $g && $g == $b && $b == 128)
                   ++$grey;
           }
       }

       return $grey < 12;
   }
   ```
2. another method i just try to save file with `file_put_contents` it's working the same like `ImageMagick` but also stuck on bad image.
3. i try to convert binary data to hex code to check `\xFF\xD9` for image type, and try to catching the terminator (null byte). But was unsuccessfully.

**The question, how to catch when the image (as binary data) is bad (corrupted)? Because my task shouldn't stuck while the cron is running. `ImageMagick` do not return an exception while is writing, or the `file_put_contents` writing to the file.**

*Regards, Donatas*

Comment: When I was working with RETS recently I was able to get the images as URLs that I could easily download/import places. It didn't come over with the listing itself, though, I had to query for it after I had the listings: https://github.com/mbitson/RETS-To-Wordpress/blob/master/a-full_pull.php#L62 - I'm sure your server is different, but you may want to look into if this is a possibility.

Comment: from mine situation i can't choose to get image files or their binary data. Just binary data. But thanks for your suggestion Mikel.

Comment: if i do something like:

$photos = $this->client->GetObject('Property', 'Photo', $systemId, '*', 1);

i'am getting error:

RETS ReplyCode="20414" ReplyText="Location=1 is not supported Reference ID

so it's look like, server doesn't support getting just a URL.